How to implement self paced multitask weighted loss (Kendall et al. 2018) in pytorch?
In this study authors introduce an equation (equation 7) to weigh the individual losses for different tasks of neural networks.
I want to implement this as a function in pytorch so that I can use for my model. So far, what I have tried is:
import torch

# function to apply uncertainty weighing on the losses
def apply_uncertainty_weights(sigma, loss):

    """
    This function applies uncertainty weights on the given loss. 
    NOTE: This implementation is based on the study Kendall et al. 2018 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07115)

    Arguments:
    sigma: A NN learned uncertainty value (initialised as torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))
    loss: The calculated losss between the prediction and target

    Returns:
    weighted_loss: Weighted loss
    """

    # apply uncertainty weighthing
    # This is the formula in the publication -> weighted_loss = (1 / (2 * sigma**2)) * loss + torch.log(sigma)
    # but we can't use it as it won't be numerically stable/differentiable (e.g. when sigma is predicted to be 0)
    # instead use the following
    sigma = torch.nn.functional.softplus(sigma) + torch.tensor(1e-8) # this makes sure sigma is never exactly 0 or less otherwise the following functions wont work
    log_sigma_squared = torch.log(sigma ** 2) # this is log(sigma^2)
    precision = (1/2) * torch.exp(-log_sigma_squared) # this is 1/sigma^2
    log_sigma = (1/2) * log_sigma_squared # this is log(sigma)
    weighted_loss = precision * loss + log_sigma

    # return the weighted loss
    return weighted_loss

But strangely this implementation gives me negative loss values during training. What am I doing wrong?

The first thing I noticed was that your code returns a tensor of losses, but what is expected is a single scalar value. Here are a couple of (unofficial) implementations of this paper on Github [1] [2]
This could be an implementation in Pytorch
def apply_uncertainty_weights(sigmas_sq, losses):
    """
    Applies uncertainty weights on multiple task losses.
    
    Args:
        sigmas_sq (torch.Tensor): A tensor of learned variances (sigmas squared) for each task.
        losses (torch.Tensor): A tensor of individual task losses.
        
    Returns:
        torch.Tensor: The total weighted loss.
    """
    precisions = 1.0 / (2.0 * sigmas_sq)

    # 1/2.0 is applied to the last additive part because we are doing log(sigma_sq) which is basically 2 * log(sigma) 
    weighted_losses = precisions * losses + (1.0 / 2.0) * torch.log(sigmas_sq)

    total_loss = torch.sum(weighted_losses)

    return total_loss

Seems to be produce a positive loss value
import torch

sigmas_sq = torch.tensor([0.5, 1.0, 2.0], requires_grad=True)
losses = torch.tensor([0.2, 0.4, 0.1])

total_loss = apply_uncertainty_weights(sigmas_sq, losses)

print(total_loss)



Thanks for your help! This function is applying weights to a single task (loss) so it returns a single loss (the inputs to the functions are single sigma and single loss)

Do you suggest to make NN learn sigma squared directly, instead of sigma? If so, why?

Also, your function returns a negative loss when the sigma squared learned by neural networks and loss <1.  E.g. please see your own example where sigma_sq=0.5, loss=0.2. the resulting weighted loss=-0.1466

Just to clarify, do you require your loss function to work with a batch of examples or just one example? (each example in itself will contain information from many tasks I understand that)

I have a loss function (mse) that I use to calculate the loss for each task. The loss function already deals with the batches. and then, I apply uncertainty weighing after calculating the loss.
